# How to create a block of vocabulary in drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, taxonomy

I've to create a block in Drupal 7 where I want to show the vocabularies without their child items.

How do I create it?

Any help will be appreciated.

Block should look like this -

Vocabulary-1

Vocabulary-2

Vocabulary-3

Answer (score 1):

In general, the easiest solution is to create a View of taxonomy terms and sort & filter based on your needs.

Views provides the taxonomy term (with depth) field to make handling the parent/child relationshop easy.

P.S.: Your block example only shows the vocabularies, instead of their terms and their child terms. Consider amending it so it's clearer what you need.

Comment: Thanks Hendrik for your reply, but can you please provide me the steps to create this view cause I'm not much aware with the views.

Comment: @Kamlesh Look for answers regarding Views, there are a lot of tutorials out there about creating Views.